# 3 Column Layout-Attempting to master plain layout before css frameworks

Tags: html, css, layout

So I have a three column layout which on the surface seems to be working fine. However when you inspect the page in the developer tools, you can see that the third column in the middle's margin is actually overlapping with the second and third columns that I've floated on either side. Furthermore when I attempted to use media queries it seems like it's not working out for mobile devices. I know I can use a framework like flexbox or bootstrap but I honestly want to learn how to do this BEFORE i use a framework. I don't wanna rely on that in case i get in a coding interview and they ask me to do this without a framework.

So in short:
-I want to make my margin smaller on a three column layout.
-I would like a column layout on mobile devices. 
My code is below

```
 `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Nav Page </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="le.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Column Layout</h1>
<div class="col1">
  <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
    nostrud exercitation ullamco
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in
    voluptate velit esse cillum dolor
     e eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
     Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
     non proident, sunt in culpa qui
     officia deserunt mollit anim id
     est laborum."
      </p>
</div>

<div class="col2">
  <h2>Column 2</h2>
  <p>
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
  commodo consequat. Duis aute
  irure dolor in reprehenderit in
  voluptate velit esse cillum dolor
   e eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
   Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
   non proident, sunt in culpa qui
   officia deserunt mollit anim id
   est laborum."
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col3">
  <h2>Column 3</h2>
  <p>
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
  commodo consequat. Duis aute
  irure dolor in reprehenderit in
  voluptate velit esse cillum dolor
   e eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
   Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
   non proident, sunt in culpa qui
   officia deserunt mollit anim id
   est laborum."
    </p>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
`
```

This is my CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col1 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col2 {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col3 {

width:25%;
heigth: 50px;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid black;

}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .col1 {
    float:none;

  }

  .col2 {
    float:none;

  }

  .col3 {
    float:none;

  }
}
```

Comment: `flexbox` has nothing to do with frameworks, it is part of CSS

Comment: aha! so it's no problem for me to learn it properly as part of the process.

Comment: You can alternatively go with CSS grid, which is not a framework, but built-in within CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure CSS, use Grid instead of floats, floats is the old way of doing layouts.

```css
/* general style */

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

/* css grid layout */

.layout{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 4rem;

    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.layout div{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
  
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .layout{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;

        grid-gap: 2rem;

        padding: 0 1rem;
    }
    
}
```

```html
    <h1>Column Layout</h1>

    <div class="layout">
        <div>
            <h1>Column 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor e eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>Column 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor e eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>Column 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolor e eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```